# What are the dangers of setting outWidth and outHeight instead of inSampleSize for decoding bitmap

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, bitmapfactory

To resize a bitmap in android, I am thinking of doing

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 1;
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options);
// options.inSampleSize = ImageResizer.calculateInSampleSize(options, x, y);
options.outWidth = x;
options.outHeight = y;
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options);
```

Please, notice which line is commented out. How would my approach differ (compare and contrast) with the more usual

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 1;
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options);
options.inSampleSize = ImageResizer.calculateInSampleSize(options, x, y);
// options.outWidth = x;
// options.outHeight = y;
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options);
```

How about if I keep all of them? As in

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 1;
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options);
options.inSampleSize = ImageResizer.calculateInSampleSize(options, x, y);
options.outWidth = x;
options.outHeight = y;
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are the dangers of setting outWidth and outHeight instead of inSampleSize for decoding bitmap

`outWidth` and `outHeight` are output values. They are not input values. Setting them yourself will do nothing useful.